# Best way to represent items that can only be in 2 states

Tags: database, database-design, erd

I have a situation where I have a disjoint relationship (in this case, the context is vehicles and their types) and I am unsure how best to represent the data outside of that relationship. The overall context is a rental DB.

My current model looks like:

[VEHICLE]----[MODEL]-----(d)----[VAN] & [CAR] (As seperate tables)

From here I also have a RENTAL table that will eventually hold the data making up an entire rental booking. However, obviously a vehicle is either currently rented or isn't or maybe reserved (Design decision).

I thought to have a RESERVED table that'll contain the vehicles that are reserved along with customer info, and the primary key from there could be used along in the RENTAL table. But then I thought where do the non-currently rented vehicles reside. Do I create 2 tables, AVAILABLE & BOOKED?

Answer (score 0):

Just model VEHICLES and BOOKINGS. To get available vehicles, a LEFT JOIN with bookings will allow you to find vehicles which aren't booked. A rental is a current or past booking, a reservation is a future booking.

Comment: Thanks, I will take this into consideration and test it against the rest of the EERD.

Comment: I would add CUSTOMER.